# get the file location and name file

Tags: php, netbeans, browser, textbox, xampp

i want to getting file name and path, then it writed on textboy
this is what i already tried

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input placeholder="path" type="text" name="path" tabindex="2" required>
    <input type="file" name="browse" value="browse">
    <input type="submit" name="convert" value="convert">
        <?php if(isset($_POST['browse'])){
            $path=$_POST['abc'];
        }
        ?>

</body>
```

Comment: my wish is after i click browse button then textbox 'name' the text is changed like
/home/directory1/directory2/okay.txt
(/path then /file name)

Comment: Your question is not well formated, we cannot understand correctly what you want. Take your time and edite it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you need to use `$_FILES`.

`$_FILES['browse']['tmp_name']` will give you the temporary storage name of the file that was uploaded. This array also has another key `$_FILES['browse']['name']` that returns just the file name of the file uploaded.

You will need to create a script on your own that takes the temporary file from `$_FILES['browse']['tmp_name']` and save it into a more permanent directory like `/home/user/public_html/uploads/*`, once you do that, you should know the upload path I hope.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php